# How to make SFINAE check less verbose?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, c++14, sfinae

I have several overloading functions like below:

```
    template<typename T>
    struct Point {
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T>
            x, y;
    };


    // These are two functions accepting only Point<> type.

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t < std::is_class_v<T>
        && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::x)>
        && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::y)>
        && sizeof(T) == sizeof(decltype(T::x)) + sizeof(decltype(T::y)), T>
        get(const char* key, T defaultValue)
    {
        //  do something ..
        return defaultValue;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void set(const char* key, std::enable_if_t < std::is_class_v<T>
        && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::x)>
        && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::y)>
        && sizeof(T) == sizeof(decltype(T::x)) + sizeof(decltype(T::y)), T> value)
    {
        //  do something ..
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t <std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T>
    get(const char* key, T defaultValue)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t <std::is_enum_v<T>, T>
    get(const char* key, T defaultValue)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    // There are others overloading get<>(), set<>() for other types.


    // Then call them
    auto pod1 = get<int>(key, {});// OK
    auto pod2 = get<float>(key, {});// OK
    auto enm = get<SomeEnum>(key, {});// OK
    auto pt1 = get<Point<int>>(key, {}); // OK
    auto pt2 = get<Point<std::string>>(key, {}); // failed - correctly.
```

So far the code works well but they look quite verbose.

What I want here is what is the neatest way to avoid repetition of checking Point<> type in get/set functions?.

I have tried like these but they do not work:

```
    template <typename T>
    using is_point_t = std::enable_if_t <
        std::is_class_v<T>
        && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::x)>
        && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::y)>
        && (sizeof(T) == sizeof(decltype(T::x)) + sizeof(decltype(T::y))), T>;


    template <typename T>
    is_point_t<T>
    get(const char* key, T defaultValue)
    {
        // do something
        return defaultValue;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void set(const char* key, is_point_t<T> value)
    {
    // do something
    }


    //   Or even like this, it also fails

    template <typename T>
    inline constexpr bool is_point_v = std::is_class_v<T>
        && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::x)> 
        && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::y)>
        && (sizeof(T) == sizeof(decltype(T::x)) + sizeof(decltype(T::y)));

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t <is_point_v<T>, T>
        get(const char* key, T defaultValue) 
        {
            // do something
            return defaultValue;
        }

    template <typename T>
        void set(const char* key, 
        std::enable_if_t <is_point_v<T>, T> value) 
        {
            // do something
        }
```

In MSVC 2019 
*error C1001:  An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
error C1001:  To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.*

Comment: Both of your solutions are correct, you will have to nudge them around until you work around your compiler's bugs...

Comment: SFINAE on data members doesn't make much sense. If you want to preclude `Point` from being instantiated with non-arithmetic type, `static_assert` would be much more convenient.

Comment: I think your long chains of `enable_if` checks are an attempt to invent [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). Once those make it to the fine compiler near you, all this could be expressed more naturally.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik May you shine a bit clearer? an example should be appreciated.

Comment: You'll be able to write something like this: `template <typename T> concept PointLike = std::is_class_v<T> && requires(T p) { requires std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(p.x)>; requires std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(p.y)>; };` and then `template <PpintLike T> T get(...);` or equivalently `template <typename T> T get(...) requires PointLike<T>;` Not tested - I don't actually have a compiler with concept support handy.

Comment: Or were you asking about `static_assert` part? That's easy: `template <typename T> struct Point { T x, y; static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "Point can only use arithemetic types"); };`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just stick with only C++11/14. Your example of static_assert does not help because the get/set have to deal (overloading) with various data types, and additionally, the those functions must accept 'point' type as any struct having two members (x and y), not only the Point<> which is given in my code.